# Find $(m, n) $ such that $u_{m, n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(m n + k)!}{(m n - m k)! ((m + 1)k + 1)!} $ is integer.

Tags: number-theory

Zagier's problem([http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/Zagier/Problems.html](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/%7Ejohn/Zagier/Problems.html)) is interesting, so I generalize the problem.

> Define a sequence $u_{m, 1}, u_{m, 2}, \cdots $ by the formula
>
> $$u_{m, n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(m n + k)!}{(m n - m k)! ((m + 1)k + 1)!}.$$
>
> Find $(m, n)$ such that $u_{m, n}$ is integer.

Now I find the following numbers.

(2, 2755452), (2, 4570452), (3, 3006), (3, 401781), (3, 528531), (5, 196), (7, 26).

For example, $u_{7, 26}$ is 44296575390001702400727108630616445125994678211370369389.

P.S.

If $m = 1$, there aren't such numbers because this problem is equvalent to the following problem.
([Are there any number $n$ such that $a_n = 0 \mod (2n + 1) $ where $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 4, a_{n + 2}=3 a_{n + 1} - a_{n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1736156/are-there-any-number-n-such-that-a-n-0-mod-2n-1-where-a-0-1-a-1))